# Hilbert-Peano curve to scan image of arbitrary size

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, rasterizing, hilbert-curve, space-filling-curve

I have written an implementation of Hilbert-Peano space filling curve in Python (from a Matlab one) to flatten my 2D image:

```
def hilbert_peano(n):
    if n<=0:
        x=0
        y=0
    else:
        [x0, y0] = hilbert_peano(n-1)
        x = (1/2) * np.array([-0.5+y0, -0.5+x0, 0.5+x0, 0.5-y0])
        y = (1/2) * np.array([-0.5+x0, 0.5+y0, 0.5+y0, -0.5-y0])

    return x,y
```

However, the classical Hilbert-Peano curve only works for multi-dimensionnal array whose shape is a power of two (ex: 256*256 or 512*512 in case of a 2D array (image)).

Does anybody know how to extend this to an array of arbitrary size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally choose, as suggested by Betterdev as adaptive curves are not that straigthforward [1], to compute a bigger curve and then get rid of coordinates which are outside my image shape:

```
# compute the needed order
order = np.max(np.ceil([np.log2(M), np.log2(N)]))
# Hilbert curve to scan a 2^order * 2^order image
x, y = hilbert_peano(order)
mat = np.zeros((2**order, 2**order))
# curve as a 2D array
mat[x, y] = np.arange(0, x.size, dtype=np.uint)
# clip the curve to the image shape
mat = mat[:M, :N]
# compute new indices (from 0 to M*N)
I = np.argsort(mat.flat)
x_new, y_new = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0, N, dtype=np.uint), np.arange(0, M, dtype=np.uint))
# apply the new order to the grid
x_new = x_new.flat[I]
y_new = y_new.flat[I]
```

[1] Zhang J., Kamata S. and Ueshige Y., "A Pseudo-Hilbert Scan Algorithm for Arbitrarily-Sized Rectangle Region"

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and have written an algorithm that generates a Hilbert-like curve for rectangles of arbitrary size in 2D and 3D. Example for 55x31: [curve55x31](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8csnv.png)

The idea is to recursively apply a Hilbert-like template but avoid odd sizes when halving the domain dimensions. If the dimensions happen to be powers of two, the classic Hilbert curve is generated.

```
def gilbert2d(x, y, ax, ay, bx, by):
    """
    Generalized Hilbert ('gilbert') space-filling curve for arbitrary-sized
    2D rectangular grids.
    """

    w = abs(ax + ay)
    h = abs(bx + by)

    (dax, day) = (sgn(ax), sgn(ay)) # unit major direction
    (dbx, dby) = (sgn(bx), sgn(by)) # unit orthogonal direction

    if h == 1:
        # trivial row fill
        for i in range(0, w):
            print x, y
            (x, y) = (x + dax, y + day)
        return

    if w == 1:
        # trivial column fill
        for i in range(0, h):
            print x, y
            (x, y) = (x + dbx, y + dby)
        return

    (ax2, ay2) = (ax/2, ay/2)
    (bx2, by2) = (bx/2, by/2)

    w2 = abs(ax2 + ay2)
    h2 = abs(bx2 + by2)

    if 2*w > 3*h:
        if (w2 % 2) and (w > 2):
            # prefer even steps
            (ax2, ay2) = (ax2 + dax, ay2 + day)

        # long case: split in two parts only
        gilbert2d(x, y, ax2, ay2, bx, by)
        gilbert2d(x+ax2, y+ay2, ax-ax2, ay-ay2, bx, by)

    else:
        if (h2 % 2) and (h > 2):
            # prefer even steps
            (bx2, by2) = (bx2 + dbx, by2 + dby)

        # standard case: one step up, one long horizontal, one step down
        gilbert2d(x, y, bx2, by2, ax2, ay2)
        gilbert2d(x+bx2, y+by2, ax, ay, bx-bx2, by-by2)
        gilbert2d(x+(ax-dax)+(bx2-dbx), y+(ay-day)+(by2-dby),
                 -bx2, -by2, -(ax-ax2), -(ay-ay2))

def main():
    width = int(sys.argv[1])
    height = int(sys.argv[2])

    if width >= height:
        gilbert2d(0, 0, width, 0, 0, height)
    else:
        gilbert2d(0, 0, 0, height, width, 0)
```

A 3D version and more documentation is available at https://github.com/jakubcerveny/gilbert

Answer (score 1):

I found this page by Lutz Tautenhahn:

"Draw A Space-Filling Curve of Arbitrary Size" (http://lutanho.net/pic2html/draw_sfc.html)

The algorithm doesn't have a name, he doesn't reference anyone else and the sketch suggests he came up with it himself.

I wonder if this is possible for a z order curve and how?

[1][Draw A Space-Filling Curve of Arbitrary Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35292214/draw-a-space-filling-curve-of-arbitrary-size)

Comment: While its true the classical hilbert curve is based on power of 2 since it's a fractal you can also ignore at some cost. But to answer your question. No.

Comment: How would you modify the original curve to get rid of the power of 2 hypothesis?

Comment: For example try a longer curve!?

Comment: I thought about that but I will have to cut a part of the curve to fit my image and thus I will lose the property that two spatially close pixels will also be close on the space filling curve.